# sending email using a profiler, I want sent email should display in sent Item. Is there any way to do that?

Tags: sql-server, database, email

I have created profiler in MS sql and sending email using a profiler.

Everything is working file.

But, now I want sent email should display in sent Item. Is there any way to do that? I am using office365 for email service.

Screen shot of email configuration of a profiler.

[image]

Screen shot of email sent item.

[image]

Comment: I think you cannot. There is an open request about the same need.  https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/264636-general/suggestions/17035333-smtp-relay-via-office-365-keep-copy-in-sent-item

Comment: yes @FabrizioAccatino, I had googled it and not found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Update the answer.
Please add the @COPY_RECIPIENTS as below and check the sent item.

MSDB.DBO.SP_SEND_DBMAIL 
@COPY_RECIPIENTS        = 'Add email recipient to keep sent emails'

Comment: No, I don't want to check all sent emails. I want Keep copy in Sent Items of email.